# ubuntu usb wifi driver install

Tags: wireless, usb

I have two different usb wifi adapter, they are using different wifi driver, one is currently using is running rtl88x2bu driver, it works well, another not working on this driver, it is in 802.11ac protocol, so can I install another 802.11 driver like 8812au on the same computer ? just afraid it will effect the 88x2bu driver, anyone knows this, thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install both drivers. The devices have different USB IDs and should load a proper driver.

Theoretically there may be a problem if some driver is not written very well... But you can always uninstall one or fix it in the code.

As it is written, it is hard to tell more.